# Django Headers and Middleware

Tags: python, django, middleware

I've created a middleware which it checks for api_key when interacting with my api

```
class APIKeyMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Allow access to Django admin without an API key
        if request.path.startswith(reverse('admin:index')):
            return self.get_response(request)

        # Allow access to Swagger documentation without an API key
        if request.path.startswith('/api/docs/'):
            return self.get_response(request)

        api_key = request.META.get('HTTP_API_KEY')  # Assuming the API key is sent in the 'API_KEY' header

        if api_key:
            try:
                api_key_obj = APIKey.objects.get(key=api_key, is_active=True)
                request.user = api_key_obj.user
            except APIKey.DoesNotExist:
                return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid API key.'}, status=401)
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'API key is missing.'}, status=401)

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

However when debugging my META I cannot find any API_KEY that was passed in the headers there.

I know it has to do with some other middleware which might get rid of my API_KEY and therefore not appearing in my META.

Can anyone help here ??

My middleware :

```
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'users.middleware.APIKeyMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
```